# É possível construir um app HTML5 para Android com Material Design?

Tags: android, material-design

Gostaria de saber se é possível desenvolver um app html/css/js para android usando material design. Se não, existe algum framework que tenha o visual?

Comment: Da sim, aqui no Brasil é bastante usando de um look nesses site ele explica um pouco http://canaltech.com.br/dica/apps/Como-criar-um-aplicativo/

Comment: você pode dá uma olhada em https://material.angularjs.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, você pode.

Hoje temos bastante opções para isso, você pode desenvolver sua aplicação utilizando algum framework CSS responsivo como Bootstrap e outros, mas eu recomendo você dar uma olhada no [**Polymer**](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/) que é um framework sob licença [*BSD*](http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt) baseado em Material Design, também recomendo uma junção com [**Phonegap**](http://phonegap.com/) para o build da aplicação. caso seja familiarizado com Angularjs recomendo também o [**material.angularjs.org**](http://material.angularjs.org).

Comment: Esse Polymer, me pareceu bem interessante, e pelo que vi é um projeto da Google (ou apoiado por eles).

Comment: eu uso o phonegap com o material.angularjs ou só o angularjs por si só já é suficiente para construir o app?

Answer (score 2):

Sim.

Basta adicionar um CSS que faça toda a estilização do HTML (e obviamente utilizar corretamente os elementos de acordo com a especificação do CSS).

Conheço dois CSSs prontos que fazem isso. Se você gosta de Bootstrap, recomendo o [Material Design for Bootstrap](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/); se não, recomendo o [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Talvez essa pergunta seja fechada "como baseado em opinião".

Mas acho mesmo assim valido indicar caminhos, então, lá vai minha resposta "baseada em opinião e experiência":

Como o Material Design é uma [diretriz de design da Google](http://www.google.com/design/) e não somente para Android, como também para todas as suas áreas de atuação, incluindo aqui [Web Developer](https://material.angularjs.org/#/). Então uma opção fornecida por eles (Google) é o [angular.js for Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/), e nesta mesma linha só que para desenvolvimento de web apps híbridos há o [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) que utiliza angular.js em suas Views.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) para gerar o aplicativo baseado em um projeto web. É um framework bem maduro.

Para o layout de sua aplicação, você pode usar o [Bootstrap Material Design](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design)